# Operaciones con fechas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Dispongo de un DataFrame (`df`), en el cual las fechas se encuentran en el formato `datetime64(ns)` (2017-09-18). Necesito implementar en un script de Python, la siguiente sentencia:

```
Fech_Act = pd.Timestamp("2018-08-02")

df["TAE"] = ((1 +((df["Val_Act"]/df["Imp_Inv"])^(1/df["Fech_Act"] - Fech_Inv))-1))^365-1
```

Su ejecución me devuelve el error

> ```
> TypeError: cannot perform __rtruediv__ with this index type: DatetimeIndex
> ```

¿Cómo puedo resolver este problema?

¿Hay alguna manera de convertir las fechas en números para realizar operaciones aritméticas, tal y como las ejecuta Excel?.

He intentado esta opción.

```
import arrow
df["TAE"] = ((1 +((df["Val_Act"]/df["Imp_Inv"])^(1/arrow.get(df["Fech_Inv"]) - Fech_Act))-1))^365-1
```

Me devuelve el error

```
TypeError: Can't parse single argument type of '<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>'
```

He probado con esta otra opción

```
from datetime import datetime
date_format = "%Y-%m-%d"
Fech_Act = datetime.strptime("2018-08-02", date_format)
df["TAE"] = ((1 +((df["Val_Act"]/df["Imp_Inv"])^(1/ datetime.strptime(df["Fech_Inv"],date_format) - Fech_Act))-1))^365-1
```

También sin éxito. Me devuelve.

```
TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series
```

La solución final ha sido:

```
    # Calcular TAE:
diferencia = fech_fin-fech_ini
TAE = (1+((cotz_fin*opcion/cotz_ini*opcion)**(1/diferencia.days)-1))**365-1
TAE
```

Comment: Hola efueyo he revertido la edición, no se debe  forzar el uso de etiquetas en los títulos, eso es función de las etiquetas. mírate la publicación de Meta [¿Qué significa “no deberías forzar una etiqueta en el título”?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2464/qu%c3%a9-significa-no-deber%c3%adas-forzar-una-etiqueta-en-el-t%c3%adtulo).

Comment: En cuanto a tu problema,  sería bueno que pudieras proveer un ejemplo del DataFrame para poder reproducir el problema  y que explicaras que intentas conseguir en base a él. No hay problema con operar con fechas cuando la operación tenga lógica (por ejemplo restarlas), pero dividir un escalar entre una fecha o viceversa no tiene mucho sentido (¿Qué es `(10/08/2018) / 3`?), otra cosa es dividir `Timedelta` entre un escalar, por ejemplo (`pd.Timedelta('1 days') / 3` nos retorna 
`Timedelta('0 days 08:00:00'`).

Comment: El error con `arrow` se debe a que `df["Fech_Inv"]` es una Serie, una columna, cuando `get` lo que espera es un solo elemento. El caso de `strptime` es similar, aparte que lo que hace es obtener un objeto `datetime` a partir de una cadena... Pero aún no se muy bien que quieres conseguir con ese código, falta contexto, ¿Qué contiene `df["Fech_Inv"]` y qué pretendes conseguir "invirtiendola"?  Si es una fecha (datetime, datetime64, etc) no tiene sentido alguno... Es posible que estemos ante un [problema XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)...

Comment: Intento clacular el TAE de una inversión, con una fórmula que me funciona en Excel. Lo que intento es dividir 1 entre el número que resulta de la diferencia entre dos fechas. En Excel si paso a número el formato de una celda "fecha", devuelve un número con el que puedo operar. ¿Se puede conseguir lo mismo en Python?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando hablas de "convertir las fechas en números para realizar operaciones aritméticas, tal y como las ejecuta Excel", supongo que lo que quieres decir es cómo saber los días transcurridos entre dos fechas dadas.

Por ejemplo, para calcular los días y segundos transcurridos entre el 1/12/1999 y hoy:

```
from datetime import datetime

fecha1 = datetime(1999, 12, 1)
fecha2 = datetime.now()

diferencia = fecha2 - fecha1

print("días transcurridos....: %d" % diferencia.days)
print("segundos transcurridos: %d" % diferencia.seconds)
```